# Process user data in PHP from JavaScript in HTML with multiple selections

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

just a fair warning: I'm a HTML, PHP and JavaScript noob.

I wrote code to get multiple selection boxes, where the selectable content from the second box is dependent on the
selection of the first box.

So like:

```
Brands:      if Asus is selected the next box:                     and the last box is prime is selected:
Asus         Prime                                                 B560
MSI          Plus                                                  Z590 etc.
```

This has to be expendable to newer models, brands etc.

The Code I have so far:
(hersteller means manufacturer)

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head></head>

<body>


<form name="form1" id="form1" action="redir.php">
  

    Hersteller: <select name="hersteller" id="hersteller">

      <option value="" selected="selected">-wählen-</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>

    Modell: <select name="model" id="model">
      <option value="" selected="selected">-wählen-</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    Chipset: <select name="chipid" id="chipid">
      <option value="" selected="selected">-wählen-</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="weiter">

    <script>var subjectObject = {
      "Asus": {
        "Prime": ["B560", "Z490", "Z590", "Z690"],
        "ProArt": ["Z490"],
        "ROG": ["Z690 ITX"]
      },
      "MSI": {
        "Torpedo": ["Z490", "Z590", "Z690"]
      }
    }
    window.onload = function() {
      var subjectSel = document.getElementById("hersteller");
      var topicSel = document.getElementById("model");
      var chapterSel = document.getElementById("chipid");
      for (var x in subjectObject) {
        subjectSel.options[subjectSel.options.length] = new Option(x, x);
      }
      subjectSel.onchange = function() {

        chapterSel.length = 1;
        topicSel.length = 1;

        for (var y in subjectObject[this.value]) {
          topicSel.options[topicSel.options.length] = new Option(y, y);
        }
      }
      topicSel.onchange = function() {

        chapterSel.length = 1;

        var z = subjectObject[subjectSel.value][this.value];
        for (var i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
          chapterSel.options[chapterSel.options.length] = new Option(z[i], z[i]);
        }
      }
    }</script>
    
  </form> 
</body>
```

redir.php

```
<?php


$hersteller = $_POST["hersteller"];
$chipid = $_POST["chipid"];
$model = $_POST["model"];

if ($hersteller = "Asus") {
    if($model = "Prime"){
        if($chipid = "B560"){
            header("Location: /driver_sites/Asus_Prime_B560.html"); 
        }
    }

exit();
}

//elseif ($items = 'Item2') {
//header("Location: item2.php");
//}
?>
```

I want to process the data selected and redirect to a specific site. For example
if the user selects "Asus" -> "Prime" -> "B560" and clicks on "weiter" (submit), it should redirect him to
a page like Asus_Prime_B560.html

How can this be done?
Thanks in advance :)

I tried multiple ways in PHP but nothing seems to work and my knowlege is limited.
Also, I searched what feels like the entire internet but to no avail.

Comment: Instead of all the if-statements, have you tried a single if statement with "&&" operators instead? as in: `if ($hersteller = "Asus" && $model = "Prime"... etc.)`

Comment: Yes I've tried that but it doesn't work... :/

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your problem, what about changing your "redir.php" file as follows:

```
<?php
$hersteller = $_POST["hersteller"];
$chipid = $_POST["chipid"];
$model = $_POST["model"];

$page = $hersteller.'_'.$model.'_'.$chipid.'.html';
header("Location: /driver_sites/".$page);
```

What this does is build the "page filename" based on the inputs and just redirect to it. Let's say that the user selected following values:

```
$hersteller = 'Asus';
$model = 'Prime';
$chipid = 'B560';
$page = $hersteller.'_'.$model.'_'.$chipid.'.html';
```

$page is now => Asus_Prime_B560.html

This example implies that all pages have the same format HERSTELLER_MODEL_CHIPID.html

Edit:
Based on your comment I will add some info

When you see some URL containing ?some=thing&foo=bar the part after the ? (question mark) is called query string. This query string parameters can be accessed by PHP using the $_GET superglobal (i.e. to read param foo i can do

```
$foo = $_GET['foo']; //$foo now contains "bar"
```

On the other end, if the form has been submitted using the POST method (<form method="post" ....>) the the data can be accessed using the $_POST superglobal

```
$something = $_POST['paramNam'];
```

Comment: This sadly doesn't work. The Link it's trying to redirect to is: "file:///C:/Users/username/html-stuff/DependenceChoice/redir.php?hersteller=Asus&model=Prime&chipid=B560"

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It's because you're using $_POST but the "method" parameter on the <form> element is not set so it uses GET as request method ($_GET in PHP). Try add <form method="post" to your form or change the $_POST to $_GET

Comment: Thanks for helping me through this! 

So I added the method but the problem still persists.
"<form method="post" name="form1" id="form1" action="redir.php">

Comment: Are you working on a webserver (even if it's local) or are you working locally? When you press the submit button does your browser navigate to "file:///C:/Users/username/html-stuff/DependenceChoice/redir.php?hersteller=Asus&model=Prime&chipid=B560" ?? If it's so i guess you're working locally without a webserver. When you press the button (and working with a webserver) you should go to either yoursite.com/redir.php (or something similar) or localhost/redir.php (or similar).

Comment: Right now I'm working locally. I'm running a docker apache container right now so I can try both ways.. Sadly, none of them work :D

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. When you update your files, you need to put them into the webserver directory in order for you application to work properly (in apache for example, on unix systems, is generally /var/www/html